# How to tooltip keep active using HTML and CSS or Jquery?

Tags: html, css

I have to display tooltip without hover and clicked.This is example which i am using for keep open tooltip without hover or click but its not working.It displaying on hover.Would you please help me in this?

**Html**

```
<span class="field-tip">
 Keep open tooltip
<span class="tip-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis tellus ac lectus porta volutpat. </span>
 </span>
```

**Css**

```
/* Hover tooltips */
.field-tip {
    position:relative;
}
    .field-tip .tip-content {
        position:absolute;
        top:-10px; 
        right:9999px;
        width:200px;
        margin-right:-220px; 
        padding:10px;
        color:#000;
        background:#F9E79F;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
        -moz-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
        -o-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
        transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
            border-radius: 10px;
    }

        .field-tip .tip-content:before {
            content:' '; 
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:-16px; 
            width:0;
            height:0;
            margin-top:-8px; 
            border:8px solid transparent;
            border-right-color:#F9E79F;
        }
        .field-tip:hover .tip-content {
            right:-20px;
            opacity:1;
        }
```

Comment: use `.field-tip .tip-content {
  right: -20px;
  opacity: 1;
}` remove `:hover` also i will remove jquery tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.field-tip {
  position: relative;
}
.field-tip .tip-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 9999px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: -220px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  background: #F9E79F;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 250ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 250ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 250ms ease-out;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-out;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.field-tip .tip-content:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -16px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -8px;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #F9E79F;
}
.field-tip .tip-content {
  right: -20px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<span class="field-tip">
 Keep open tooltip
<span class="tip-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis tellus ac lectus porta volutpat. </span>
</span>
```

1. Use `.field-tip .tip-content { right: -20px; opacity: 1; }` remove `:hover`

Comment: Right Mr.guradio...i forgot to remove hover.Thanks for help.Its working

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by jquery/javascript  by hover and click event binding. Without javascript code it is not possible.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".field-tip").hover(function(){
$(this).addClass('active');
});
$(".field-tip").click(function(){
$(this).removeClass('active');
});
  
});
```

```css
/* Hover tooltips */
.field-tip {
    position:relative;
}
    .field-tip .tip-content {
        position:absolute;
        top:-10px; 
        right:9999px;
        width:200px;
        margin-right:-220px; 
        padding:10px;
        color:#000;
        background:#F9E79F;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
        -moz-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
        -o-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
        transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
            border-radius: 10px;
    }

        .field-tip .tip-content:before {
            content:' '; 
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:-16px; 
            width:0;
            height:0;
            margin-top:-8px; 
            border:8px solid transparent;
            border-right-color:#F9E79F;
        }
        .field-tip.active .tip-content {
            right:-20px;
            opacity:1;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="field-tip">
 Keep open tooltip
<span class="tip-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis tellus ac lectus porta volutpat. </span>
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    
    <head>
        
        <style>
            
            .field-tip {position:relative;top: 38px;}
            
            .tip-content {
                
                position:absolute;top:-10px;right:9999px;
                width:200px;margin-right:-220px;padding:10px;
                color:#000;background:#F9E79F;opacity:0;
                -webkit-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
                -moz-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
                -ms-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
                -o-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
                transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            
            
            .tip-content:before {
                
                content:' ';position:absolute;top:50%;left:-16px; 
                width:0;height:0;margin-top:-8px; 
                border:8px solid transparent;border-right-color:#F9E79F;
            }
            
            .tip-content {
                
                left:150px;top: 10px;opacity:1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <span class="field-tip">Keep open tooltip</span>
        
        <span class="tip-content">
            
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis tellus ac lectus porta volutpat. 
        
        </span>
        
    </body>
</html>
```